# find out ideal window size for coherence analysis - python

Tags: python, scipy

Is there a general formula I could use to calculate the ideal window for the `window` argument in the function `scipy.signal.coherence`, maybe taking into account sampling rate and number of time points?

For example, if I acquired data at a sampling rate of $1.5\texttt{Hz}$ and I have $100$ **time points**, what window size would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It depends what frequency resolution you are happy with, i.e. how
  many discrete frequencies you think are relevant to you. These frequencies will span $0$ to
  $f_s/2$, and you will get a coherence value for each.
- The frequency resolution is computed as $f_s/N$, $N$ being the size of the analysis window.

With that in mind, a here is an example:

$N = 10$ will give you $N/2 = 5$ values for your coherence function (the negative frequency part is discarded), at the following discrete frequencies spaced $f_s/N = 0.15\texttt{Hz}$ apart: $$0\texttt{Hz}, 0.15\texttt{Hz}, 0.30\texttt{Hz}, 0.45\texttt{Hz}, 0.60\texttt{Hz}$$

Note, you can also play around with the `noverlap` argument. Typical values would be $N/2$ or $N/4$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it was very helpful! What would you consider a reasonable frequency resolution to be? I'm mostly interested in very low frequencies (below 0.25 Hz). I believe matlab uses a default `L=N/4.5`, but I'm not sure what the rationale is for that choice.

Comment: I don't know your application, so you need to define what a reasonable frequency resolution is based on your requirements. You can also compute the coherence on the full $100$ points.  By the way, I'm assuming you know what coherence is, you do know it's computed between two signals right? Your question mentions "data", hence my question.